# Reason behind additional error time in this timing code

Tags: java, benchmarking

I've recently been working with some performance examples in java and came across this snippet:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
// code to be timed goes here...
long finish = System.nanoTime();
long error = System.nanoTime() - finish;
long duration = finish - start - error;
```

Now I understand **what** the code is doing, but not necessarily **why** the `error` timing is also being subtracted?

Plenty of times I've seen this kind of thing:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
// code to be timed goes here...
long finish = System.nanoTime();
long duration = finish - start;
```

But not this concept of the additional error timing before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is being done in an attempt to subtract the time it takes to execute the `long finish = System.nanoTime();` instruction. The author doesn't want the act of stopping the stopwatch to count against the code being tested.

Unless you really are dealing with nano level precision, this is overkill, and might not even really account for what the author intends.